# Can I have a list of foreign keys as a single field?

Tags: postgresql

I'm making a table called `cameras` that should be able to be "owned" by multiple users. To store this, I'd like to have a list of user ids as a field as the foreign key. I've made a little illustration below that probably explains it better.

Here is the schema I use to store users:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    username text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password text NOT NULL
);
```

And here is how I would like to store cameras:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
CREATE TABLE cameras (
    camera_id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    --- user_ids as foreign keys---
)
```

Here's the illustration (with ids swapped out with numbers for simplicity):
[image: Illustration of how users and cameras will be linked]

Would this approach be possible? Should I even be trying to link users to cameras this way or would there be a better solution?

Comment: Can a user own more than one camera? You may be looking at a [many-to-many](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/many-to-many-relationships.html) scenario. Your best option may be to create a `users_cameras` table with a `user_id, camera_id` pair for each relationship.

Comment: @DakotaMethvin This makes much more sense than my solution, I'll implement it that way instead :)